# How write a python script to send metrics data to pushgateway

Tags: python, metrics, prometheus-pushgateway

I want to send metrics data to the Prometheus push gateway to monitor CPU and memory.
What I want is to transfer `$ps aux` or `$htop` information to the push gateway.
I tried this with a bash script, but I didn't succeed, which is why I'd like to try with a python script.
The big problem for me is to convert `$ps aux` or `$htop` information to metrics data. I really don't know how to manage it.
I tried a simple code, which works correctly:

```
import requests
job_name='metrics'
instance_name='10.0.0.1:9090'
team_name='cpu'
provider='Rpi'
payload_key='cpu_utilization'
payload_value='33'

response = requests.post('http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/{j}/instance/{i}/team/{t}'.format(j=job_name, i=instance_name, t=team_name), data='{k} {v}\n'.format(k=payload_key, v=payload_value))
print(response.status_code)
```

What I want now is to modify `payload_key='cpu_utilization'` and `payload_value='33'` to a list of process as `$ps aux` or `$htop` command.

Comment: You can try execute command by `os.system(<command string here>)` and parse the output of command.

Answer (score 1):

The python command run perfectly:

```
os.system('ps –eo pid,user,%mem,cmd --sort=-%mem')
```

But how insert it into the previous code ?

I tested :

```
import requests, os
job_name='metrics'
instance_name='10.0.0.1:9090'
team_name='cpu'
provider='Rpi'
payload_key=os.system('ps –eo pid')
payload_value=os.system('ps –eo %cpu')

response = requests.post('http://localhost:9091/metrics/job/{j}/instance/{i}/team/{t}'.format(j=job_name, i=instance_name, t=team_name), data='{k} {v}\n'.format(k=payload_key, v=payload_value))
print(response.status_code)
```

But (not surprised), that doesn't run.
How can I affect PID 1 with %cpu to the metric n# 1 ? and all cpu data to a list of metrics ?

At least convert the `os.system('ps –eo pid,user,%mem,cmd --sort=-%mem')` response to a list and after do a while for the request.post wich take all the list elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to test this command :

```
$ps –eo pid,user,%mem,cmd --sort=-%mem
```

and change :

```
payload_key='cpu_utilization'
payload_value='33'
```

by the "$ps" command :

```
os.system('ps –eo pid,user,%mem,cmd --sort=-%mem')
```

maybe this would be run... or not !!